# confused on how to implement threading/multi-processing

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

I have a function that creates and active sync client, then connect to an exchange server and retrieves emails from a mailbox. The users are numbered as follows:

```
user-0@example.com
.
.
.
user-25@example.com
```

I can go through using a for loop:

```
for x in range(0, 25):
    email_function(x)
```

I would like to do multiple users simultaneously, and do not know if I should use threads or processes.

I tried this piece of code and it runs:

```
def mp_run(m):
    email_actions(m)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    operation_time = time.clock()
    jobs = []
    for m in range(25):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=mp_run(m), args=(m,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

But using process explorer, I only see a single thread.

Comment: As an aside, I think your statement `for x in range(0, 25):` will only give you addresses up to 24. So `user-25@example.com` will be missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
target=mp_run(m)
```

You're calling the `mp_run` function beforehand, and setting the `target` to `None` (the return value of the function). Since the target of `None` isn't a function, no new threads are started (and nothing happens). Change it to:

```
target=mp_run
```